# Why are stylesheets in public/stylesheets files served by Expressjs with the status 304?

Tags: css, node.js, express, http-status-code-304

I find that certain stylesheets,which I might have just updated load with a `304` status code.This is my code on the client side:

```
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/divider.min.css"/>
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{


"name": "login",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.10.1",
    "compression": "^1.3.0",
    "consolidate": "^0.10.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.11.0",
    "handlebars": "^2.0.0",
    "helmet": "^0.6.0",
    "jade": "~1.9.0",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.22",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "multer": "^0.1.7",
    "passport-dropbox": "^0.1.2",
    "passport-github": "^0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.1.4",
    "passport-http": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Can you tell me if a module like `compression` is doing this?

Comment: Maybe because there is cache and content is not modifed as 304 http status informs.

Comment: "...which I might have just updated..." Well, did you or didn't you?

Comment: @Jon I updated the stylesheet and saved it.

Comment: Maybe try `npm uninstall compression` and see if that fixes it. Not hard to check

Comment: @Jordan this worked for me,but I also had to disable the cache on Chrome as well

Comment: I've seen this come up as a solution in conjunction with this issue/module: `app.disable('etag');` Not sure if it will solve your problem or not